# SMTP on internal network

Tags: email, smtp, forwarding

We a have a Qnap which uses the internal network. We would like to setup Qnap to send on notification emails to an  internal smtp server something like 192.168.123.... which is connected to internet and forwards Notifications to given addresses. On this machine I already have post fix installed. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open relay for Qnap IP address (if it's a static IP). Edit the **/etc/postfix/main.cf** file:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.123.1
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks, ...., ....
```

You have to add Qnap IP to **mynetworks** and be sure **smtpd_recipient_restrictions** includes **permit_mynetworks**

After that reload postfix and force Qnap to send a mail. Check the maillog file to see if it's working.

Comment: thank u for feedback I've done the suggested bt qnap hangs on email send

Comment: Add your workstation IP address to mynetworks in postfix. Then use a mail client for sending a mail using your smtp. That will tell you whether the problem is postfix or Qnap.